# Attachmate data scraping macro that prints pages to file

Tags: vba, screen-scraping, extra

I recorded the following macro using Attachmate Extra! X-treme at work. I believe I'm using version 9.0. I'm trying to "scrape" data from a report that spans various screens, and print each page to a .txt or .prn file. The code as presented steps through all the necessary screens but fails to output the results to the desired file that I would like to then manipulate in MS Excel.

I'm new to Attachmate so any help would be appreciated. Is it simply a matter of adding a few lines of code to direct the output or is there a bigger picture here? Many thanks in advance for your help!

```
' Global variable declarations
Global g_HostSettleTime%
Global g_szPassword$

Sub Main()
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Get the main system object
     Dim Sessions As Object
 Dim System As Object
 Set System = CreateObject("EXTRA.System")  ' Gets the system object
 If (System is Nothing) Then
    Msgbox "Could not create the EXTRA System object.  Stopping macro playback."
    STOP
 End If
 Set Sessions = System.Sessions

 If (Sessions is Nothing) Then
    Msgbox "Could not create the Sessions collection object.  Stopping          
            macro playback."
    STOP
 End If
     '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ' Set the default wait timeout value
 g_HostSettleTime = 3000        ' milliseconds

 OldSystemTimeout& = System.TimeoutValue
 If (g_HostSettleTime > OldSystemTimeout) Then
    System.TimeoutValue = g_HostSettleTime
 End If

    ' Get the necessary Session Object
 Dim Sess0 As Object
 Set Sess0 = System.ActiveSession
 If (Sess0 is Nothing) Then
    Msgbox "Could not create the Session object.  Stopping macro playback."
    STOP
 End If
 If Not Sess0.Visible Then Sess0.Visible = TRUE
 Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)

    ' This section of code contains the recorded events
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf11>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf10>") 
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf8>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf3>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)
Sess0.Screen.Sendkeys("<Pf3>")  
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet(g_HostSettleTime)

System.TimeoutValue = OldSystemTimeout

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just utilize Excel VBA and the Attachmate Extra! Object Library to pull the desired values into Excel instead of an intermediate file.

Specifically the `getstring` function (`Function GetString(Row As Integer, Col As Integer, Length As Integer, [Page]) As String`) and drop the values on to an Excel sheet.

See below insert of VBA code which is a simple text pull.

To add the Attachmate Extra Object Library to Excel in VBA window select Tools > References > then select Attachmate Extra Object Library from list or browse for item.

You can view the objects, properties, and methods through the Excel VBA Object Browser.

```
Sub MF_Status_Test()

    ' Test Order Lookup Macro
    Set Sys = GetObject("C:\Program Files\E!PC\Sessions\Mainframe.EDP")

    Set MyScreen = Sys.Screen

    Do While ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value <> ""
        Let Order = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value
        MyScreen.SendKeys (Order)

        MyScreen.SendKeys ("<enter>")
        Found1st = MyScreen.WaitHostQuiet(150)

        Dt = MyScreen.getstring(7, 11, 8)
        Let ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1") = Dt
        Let Dt = ""

        ST = MyScreen.getstring(6, 11, 2) & MyScreen.getstring(17, 12, 3)
        Let ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1") = ST
        Let ST = ""

        Amt = MyScreen.getstring(3, 53, 10)
        Let ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Range("A1") = Trim(Amt)
        Let Amt = ""

        MyScreen.SendKeys ("<PF8>")

        Dt = MyScreen.getstring(7, 11, 8)
        Let ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Range("A1") = Dt
        Let Dt = ""

        ST = MyScreen.getstring(6, 11, 2) & MyScreen.getstring(17, 12, 3)
        Let ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Range("A1") = ST
        Let ST = ""

        Amt = MyScreen.getstring(3, 53, 10)
        Let ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Range("A1") = Trim(Amt)
        Let Amt = ""

        Found1st = MyScreen.WaitHostQuiet(150)

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't actually need the object library to do this, although it does help somewhat for debugging etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to hook into an Attachmate EXTRA! session from Excel, rather than the other way around.

Installing the Attachmate Object Library would probably help for debugging etc, but is not essential.

Here is a basic VBA module you can run from Excel without installing the Object Library, which will allow you to send keys to your currently open EXTRA! session and also read values from the screen:

```
Sub GetData()

Dim Sessions As Object
Dim System As Object
Dim Sess0 As Object

'Extra Objects
Set System = CreateObject("EXTRA.System")
Set Sessions = System.Sessions
Set Sess0 = System.ActiveSession
If Sess0 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Could not create the Session object.  Stopping macro playback.")
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not Sess0.Visible Then Sess0.Visible = True
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet (3000)

'Now the active EXTRA! session is bound to the Object "Sess0", we can use it like a normal VBA object:

Sess0.Screen.SendKeys ("<Pf8>") ' Press F8
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet (1000) ' Wait for 1 second for the screen to stop updating (should really do this after every keypress that causes the mainframe to update)

Sess0.Screen.MoveTo 21, 28 ' Move the cursor to row 21, column 28.

Sess0.Screen.SendKeys ("<Pf9>") ' Press F9
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet (1000)

Sess0.Screen.SendKeys ("<Tab><Tab><Tab>Logon<Enter>") ' Press Tab 3 times, then type "Logon" and press enter
Sess0.Screen.WaitHostQuiet (1000)

Dim SomeString as String
SomeString = Sess0.Screen.GetString(1, 1, 20) ' Read the first 20 characters displayed on the screen to "SomeString"

Sess0.Connected = False ' Disconnect from the mainframe session

'Tidying up
System.TimeoutValue = OldSystemTimeout
Set Sessions = Nothing
Set System = Nothing
Set Sess0 = Nothing

End Sub
```